# How to have a seperate database connection for each fork when using multiprocessing with generators in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing

I am using Keras with `fit_generator()`. My generator connects to a Database (MongoDB in my case) to fetch data for each batch. If I use the multiprocessing flag of `fit_generator()` I get this Warning:

```
UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only after forking.
```

I am connecting to the Database during `__init__()`:

```
class MyCustomGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        collection = MagicMongoDBConnector()

    def __len__(self):
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Using collection to fetch data from mongoDB
        ...

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        ...
```

I would assume I need to have a separate connection for each epoch, but unfortunately, there is no `on_epoch_begin(self)` callback available (as seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0-alpha0/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py)).

So two questions: 
How and when does Keras fork the Generator if multiprocessing is used?
How can I get rid of the MongoClient warning and connect inside each fork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a mongo DB to test on but this might work - you can get the collection (connection?) on the first get-item of each process.

```py
class MyCustomGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.collection = None

    def __len__(self):
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if self.collection is None:
            self.collection = MagicMongoDBConnector()
        # Continue with your code
        # Using collection to fetch data from mongoDB
        ...

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        ...
```

Comment: That did the trick. And collections are basically tabels within a database.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Python 3.7 you could use [os.register_at_fork](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.register_at_fork) to trigger creating the database connection

for example you could do something like:

```
from os import register_at_fork

def reinit_dbcon():
    generator_obj.collection = MagicMongoDBConnector()

register_at_fork(after_in_child=reinit_dbcon)
```

somewhere before you call `fit_generator`.  assuming the object is somewhere global